# Can't add an application from app store to my careers profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Well I can't add applications I've done to the careers profile. The link leads me to [this page](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/de/jobs/101096/ruby-on-rails-developer-university-of-california) which is weird.

Edit: In the image I uploaded on my careers profile the button "add an application" goes to the link I mentioned above.

[image: link is wrong?]

Comment: I edited my question. Hope it's clearer now

Comment: Can you add a link to **your** careers profile?

Comment: @Dawny33 are you referring to this one: careers.stackoverflow.com/nemanja-vukosavljevic-115406 ?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem - will take a look.

Comment: It works now. Thanks however solved this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed now.

We've been making some performance improvements to the Careers site, and one of these which was added a couple of days ago made a change to how URLs are generated and cached.

What happened with the "add an application" link on your profile was a hash collision with the random job listing page, so we were giving you that URL instead of the correct one.

To fix the problem, I've reverted the code change for now, and we'll take another look at it so we get the performance boost without random links going to the wrong place!